# Como detectar si un li anterior esta activo y colorear before

Tags: css, sass, design

Necesito lograr este estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo saber si el *02* esta activo y colorear la linea antes de llegar al *03* de verde?

```css
.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.progressbar .active:before {
  background-color: #31e8be;
}
.progressbar .active:after {
  background-color: #31e8be;
}
.progressbar .current:before {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  counter-increment: step;
  content: counter(step, decimal-leading-zero);
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #edf4f2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #edf4f2;
  top: 1px;
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li
    class="active">
  </li>
  <li
    class="active">
  </li>
  <li
    class="current">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás añadiendo la clase `active`, cualquier elemento posterior responde al selector `.active + *`, pero como además estás utilizando la clase `.current` puedes ser más específico en la selección.

```
.progressbar .current:before {  #movido para evitar colisiones
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.progressbar .active:before,
.progressbar .active + .current:before {   #añadido
  background-color: #31e8be;
}

.progressbar .active:after {
  background-color: #31e8be;
}
```